# When will the lock on a file on CIFS, opened for writing, timeout / be released?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, smb, cifs

Suppose I open a file from an .net app that sits on a shared disk using CIFS for writing, and

1. the process dies suddenly
2. the machine the process runs on crashes

In each case, how long would a process from another machine be prevented from writing to that file?
And is that time somehow programmatically changeable?

Comment: ime, sometimes you have to restart the server or release the file manually from the server. In summary, do your best to make sure you clean up your file handles.

Comment: I think if a client dies, and a different client requests a file, the server will ask the first client if it still has the file, notice that its not responding, and give up the lock.